# Errors when edits are saved

Tags: support, bug

The last few weeks I've regularly had an error when trying to save the edit on questions. This has always happened repeatedly for the same questions, even when refreshing the page or trying to do the same edit at a later time.

[image]

**Has anyone else noticed this too - or discovered what could be triggering these errors ?**

update: 2015-01-29 : issue still occuring.

Comment: I have seen this several times. Most often its occurred just before the site has gone down for maintenance.